# Замена DIV при наведении

Tags: html, javascript

Есть div, нужно чтобы при наведении на него, он исчезал и на его месте появлялся другой див. В дивах html код, через css не выйдет. Нужный js найти не могу.

Comment: нужный js **найти не могу**,

> [Не стоит задавать вопросы с просьбой выполнить бесплатно или за деньги какую-либо работу, связанную с программированием: форум не является фриланс-биржей.](http://hashcode.ru/faq/#heading8)


через css тоже можно сделать.

Answer (score 3):

HTML

```
<div class="div1">DIV1 
    <div class="div2">DIV2</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
div{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;    
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 300px;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;    
}
.div1{
    background: #000;
}
.div2{
    background: #f00;
    display: none;
    position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;    
}
.div1:hover .div2{
    display: block;  
    cursor: pointer;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6KzLG/ - css вариант

Answer (score 0):

Добавь в стили ему

```
display: none;
```

Answer (score 0):

Не стоит удалять элементы из DOM, проще всего взять JQuery, выбрать этот div и скрыть его с помощью метода hide().